# SQL Syntax Error On Access DB Insert

Tags: c#, ms-access, syntax-error, oledb

I don't know what I am missing but I keep getting syntax errors on insert for my access database. Here is the code I am using:

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO Users (FirstName, LastName, BirthDate, Username, 
                   Password) VALUES ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}');";
string sqlF = String.Format(sql, f, l, dob.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), u, Encrypt(p));
MessageBox.Show(sqlF);
OleDbConnection conn = DBConn(_BudgetMainDB, _BudgetMainPass);
OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
conn.Open();
cmd.CommandText = sqlF;
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Here are images of my database and syntax

[image]
[image]

Comment: A) Always use DB Parameters.  Your code will fail on names like `O'Brien` or `D'Artagne` B) never store passwords as plain text or even encrypted - hash them C) do not store dates as text - they wont act like dates

Comment: how is it this is working if you don't pass in all the Values Parameters? also I would wrap `[Password] and [UserName]` around square brackets.. cmd.ExecuteScalar() is for Select statements returning `1` row. you need to use `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` when performing the following `INSERTS, UPDATES, DELETES` also read up on how to wrap your Sql Objects around `using() { }`  construct. the current Sql has flaws

Comment: Never. Ever. Concatenate. Input. Into. SQL. - seriously, don't ever do that; this might be useful: http://blog.marcgravell.com/2017/12/dapper-prepared-statements-and-car-tyres.html

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out Password is a reserved word so i have to put it in brackets. dumb mistake :/

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but that was just one of many mistakes here. A textual column called `password` is a huge red flag that says "no! stop!" (and encrypting passwords doesn't count - that is still fundamentally broken) - add to that some *crippling* SQL injection bugs in your insert code, and you're about to leak your users passwords. Seriously: this is extremely dangerous code.